# An error in water ripple effect (Java Open GL)

Tags: java, opengl

I'm trying to implement water ripple effect on a polygon model / wireframe. I followed these two guides that are pretty clear: [2D Water](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_water.htm) and [The Water Effect Explained](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/the-water-effect-explained-r915)

Following these guides, I ended up with (in this order)

Two arrays of floats, full of zeros after my app launches expect one to start the ripple effect

```
float[][] heightMapPrev = new float[101][101];
float[][] heightMapCurr = new float[101][101];

// ... filling both arrays with 0.0f ...

heightMapCurr[30][40] = -0.5f; // changing one value to start a water wave
```

Variable to define damping of waves as they go further

```
float damping = 0.4f;
```

The algorithm itself. I loop through all the vertices, count their new y position and smoothening/damping the effect

```
// Loop through all the vertices and update their vertical position values according to their surrounding vertices' vertical positions
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {    
        // Count new vertical position of each vertex
        heightMapCurr[i][j] = (heightMapPrev[i+1][j] +
                               heightMapPrev[i-1][j] + 
                               heightMapPrev[i][j+1] + 
                               heightMapPrev[i][j-1]) % 2.0f - 
                               heightMapCurr[i][j];
        // Count water vertical velocity
        float velocity = -heightMapCurr[i][j];
        // Smooth buffers every frame to waves spread out the waves 
        float smoothed = (heightMapPrev[i+1][j] + 
                          heightMapPrev[i-1][j] + 
                          heightMapPrev[i][j+1] + 
                          heightMapPrev[i][j-1]) / 4.0f; 
        // Calculate new height of the water; reduce the effect with *2
        heightMapCurr[i][j] =  smoothed * 2 + velocity;

        // Damp ripples to make them loose energy                     
        heightMapCurr[i][j] *= damping;
    }
}
```

(Re)drawing all the vertices, inside those two for loops

```
gl.glVertex3f((float)i, heightMapCurr[i][j], (float)j); // for each vertex
```

Finally, as the guide tells me to, I swap values in both arrays - what was in the waveMapPrev is now in waveMapCurr and vice versa

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 101; j++) {
        temp[i][j] = heightMapPrev[i][j];
        heightMapPrev[i][j] = heightMapCurr[i][j];
        heightMapCurr[i][j] = temp[i][j];
    }
}
```

I though I'm clear about what is happening there but clearly I'm not, because there something wrong in my algorithm. Wave spreads from a certain point into distance, keeping circle shape, that is okay. However, water keeps "bubbling" also in the middle of the circle and once the water ripple reaches borders, everything is "bubbling" and it never stops. The ripple should probably not even hit all the borders.
[image: In the top image, you can see the water ripple going right from the specified point. The bottom image shows what happens after the ripple reaches borders. It is like this until exiting the app.]

Can you tell/explain me what I did wrong and how to correct the error? I tried for hours changing values (damping...), operators (% for /, + for -), and smoothening function, I did not succeed, though.

**Update://**
In the code above, I use modulus operator (%) instead of (/). The reason for this is just because I always get completely wrong heightMap values, the wave starts spreading to all directions including somewhere into the sky, never getting back down - like in the image below.
[image: Error in rendering when using / instead of %]

Comment: Try aligning the code of the math inside the inner loop like you would with regular C++ code, i.e., braces on new lines, indents etc. This should make it more clear what actually happens mathematically. You'll find that you can refactor the code quite a bit (using local variables, removing extraneous braces, replacing `/4*2` with a simple `/2` or even `*0.5`. Also, you are mixing integer and floating point arithmetic, so try changing all relevant constants in the math part to double (e.g. `/2.0`). I guess that from there you'll find out the error(s) by yourself :)

Comment: I just did what you said, but kept everything in floats. I would have to change the arrays to arrays of doubles which should not be necessary. I think there is a problem in the logic of the buffers or counting the new position - can't see it, though.

Comment: I didn't mean you should use `double` instead of `float`, just that you should not use `int` type constants inside floating point math, so your new code is quite fine (you missed one though, probably not that important but using only floats will prevent any intermediate type conversion by the compiler). And much more readable too like this, +1 just for that! :)

Comment: I'm glad you're happy with it :). I still can't see where the problem is :/ it's kinda strange, I though I did everything exactly as the guides say. It's basically the same what teacher told me, except some little detail that makes the damping not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found your problem. Replace the modulus operator `%` with a simple divide `/`, as both of the links you provide suggest and see what that does.

Comment: It's one of the things I already tried. The thing about this is that with damping = 0.4f and small initial vertical position of the vertex I want to start a ripple with nothing happens. Experimenting with higher damping like 0.8f, there is the effect but everything is damped immediately like there was no energy. Furthermore, to be even able to see an effect, I have to set initial vertex's position to at least 20f. Maybe I could just lower the damping now, have to experiment with this a lot I guess.

Comment: I updated the answers for you to see the reason why do I use modulus instead of standard division.

Comment: At the end, you were correct - thank you :) I've found one more guide here http://www.fabiensanglard.net/fluide/ with even simpler dampling process and it finally works as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is even simpler than what the guides propose. I have found it [here](http://www.fabiensanglard.net/fluide/)

This is the the body of the whole algorithm according to the latter guide provided, even simpler than anyone could expect.

```
// Loop through all the vertices and update their vertical position values according to their surrounding vertices' vertical positions
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {    
        // Count new vertical position of each vertex
        heightMapCurr[i][j] = (heightMapPrev[i+1][j] +
                               heightMapPrev[i-1][j] + 
                               heightMapPrev[i][j+1] + 
                               heightMapPrev[i][j-1]) / 2.0f - 
                               heightMapCurr[i][j];

        // Damp ripples to make them loose energy                    
        heightMapCurr[i][j] -= heightMapCurr[i][j] * damping;
    }
}
```